# Why Turing wasn't wrong?

Tags: church-turing-thesis

Computer science is a science and as a science each thesis can be refutable. So, why there is no "major" counter-thesis?
After all, Einstein was a well known "genius" and has lived a long life and he has got many opponents. Why isn't it the same case for Turing?

Comment: Turing had some opponents, and they may have contributed to his early death.

Comment: @Y There is one thing that bothers me in the case of Church-Turing
Thesis, which might be seen as a more general problem (beyond
Hilbert's entscheidungsproblem). It seems (feels?) that the
limitations on computability stated by the CT Thesis are not unrelated
to the discrete character of the logical and scientific discourse
which is representable by text, i.e. strings of symbols, and which seems
the only kind we are able to consider. But it is hard to grasp what
might be the origin of this limitation: mathematical consistency (in some
meta sense), physical laws, human mind/perception or other.

Comment: @babou Some people say that the Church–Turing thesis is correct for the intuitive notion of *mechanical computation*, but could be wrong for some hocus-pocus due to funky laws of physics; as long a you're interested only in mechanical computation, the Church–Turing thesis does hold. A good example is quantum computing – this is hocus-pocus, which turns out not to go beyond Turing-computability.

Comment: I love the word hocus-pocus, especially in your mouth, which shows how uncomfortable some of this can be. Talking to people in SE-Physics is however disappointing. Their certainties about their knowledge of the universe is impressively remindful of other physicists at the end of the 19th century. For people who have been working for a hundred years with two incompatible theories, and who do not know what constitutes 95% of the universe, among many other things, I find their confidence a bit surprising.

Comment: Counter-thesis to what?  It's not that you can refute all of computer science.  Instead, what is refutable is individual claims or hypotheses.  So what claim/hypothesis are you asking for a refutation or criticism of?

Comment: Turing did not propose a scientific hypothesis (which could be falsified with experiments) but a mathematical statement along with a proof. Once you accept the proof (and in this case, that's consensus), you agree that the statement is universally true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Computer science is a science only by name. In practice, it is a blend of engineering, mathematics, and empirical science.

With that out of the way, here are a few comments about the Church–Turing thesis. **First**, about the thesis itself. We can think of at least three interpretations of the Church–Turing thesis. Under the first, stronger interpretation, any computation that can be done in the physical world can be modelled by (say) a Turing machine. This is a thesis which indeed can be refuted, and people have tried to refute it, though so far unsuccessfully (Scott Aaronson suggests to regard this as a "law of nature").

The second, weaker interpretation only claims that any computation *done in practice* (now) can be modelled by a Turing machine. This thesis is essentially correct, though to make it truly correct you need to make it mathematically precise; Nachum Dershowitz and Yuri Gurevich have done just that, though their formulation doesn't necessarily reflect the intuitive content of the thesis.

The third interpretation, very related to the second, is that any pseudocode that we can describe can be implemented on a Turing machine. We use this thesis implicitly whenever we describe and analyze algorithms, both in very theoretical areas (recursion theory, computational complexity, theoretical algorithms and data structures, approximation algorithms) and in more applied areas, in which the pseudocode is often translated to code in practice.

**Second**, in practice the more interesting thesis is what is sometimes called the Cook–Karp thesis. This thesis states that the class $\mathsf{P}$ embodies all decision problems that can be solved efficiently in practice. In my view, this thesis is dubious. There are three main attacks on this thesis.

The first attack is that the class $\mathsf{P}$ is defined asymptotically, whereas we are interested in problems of finite size. It could be that for practical input size, a problem which is perhaps not in $\mathsf{P}$ can be solved efficiently (for example, small cryptosystems can be broken even if they are secure). Conversely, it could be that a problem is in $\mathsf{P}$ but it cannot be solved efficiently, since the polynomial time "kicks in" only for large problems.

This is very related to the second attack, which is that polynomial time algorithms need not be efficient: they could have a large (big O) constant or a large exponent. A good example for a large constant is fast matrix multiplication algorithms, which are not practical due to the large constant. A good example for a large exponent is deterministic primality testing (the AKS algorithm), which isn't practical due to the large exponent.

A third attack, which is more speculative at this point, is that quantum computers can efficiently solve some problems which we think classical computers cannot. While quantum computers still exist only on paper, unless we believe that there is some fundamental obstacle to constructing them (as some people indeed do, for example Gil Kalai), we have to contend that in the future the class $\mathsf{P}$ would have to be enlarged to the corresponding quantum class $\mathsf{BQP}$.

A related attack states that randomized algorithms can be stronger than deterministic ones: for example randomizes primality testing is practical while the AKS algorithm isn't. However, it is believed that "randomness doesn't help", in the sense that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{BPP}$ (which doesn't mean that randomized algorithms can't be faster; it only means that they can only be polynomially faster).

Comment: Is your reference to Gurevich about his work with Dershowitz on proving Church-Turing thesis from other axiom?

Comment: Yes, though Gurevich also has work on his own. I'll add Dershowitz to the post.

Comment: These are interesting comments, but I'm not sure what the Cook-Karp thesis has to do with the original question. Also, inasmuch as mathematics is a natural science (which is admittedly debatable) and (parts of) Computer Science are essentially a branch of mathematics, CS is certainly a science.

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't consider mathematics as science, but the point is that we shouldn't learn of the scientific nature of a field from its *name*.